# Printing very big BigIntegers

Tags: java, 64-bit, biginteger, java-7

I'm trying to figure out the following issue related to BigIntegers in Java 7 x64. I am attempting to calculate a number to an extremely high power. Code is below, followed by a description of the problem.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Demo calculation; Desired calculation: BigInteger("4096").pow(800*600)
        BigInteger images = new BigInteger("2").pow(15544);

        System.out.println(
            "The number of possible 16 bpc color 800x600 images is: "
            + images.toString());        
    }
}
```

I am encountering issues printing the result of this operation. When this code executes it prints the message but not the value of `images.toString()`.

To isolate the problem I started calculating powers of two instead of the desired calculation listed in the comment on that line. On the two systems I have tested this on, `2^15544` is the smallest calculation that triggers the problem; `2^15543` works fine.

I'm no where close to hitting the memory limit on the host systems and I don't believe that I am even close to the VM limit (at any rate running with the VM arguments `-Xmx1024M` `-Xms1024M` has no effect).

After poking around the internet looking for answers I have come to suspect that I am hitting a limit in either `BigInteger` or `String` related to the maximum size of an array (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) that those types use for internal data storage. If the problem is in `String` I think it would be possible to extend `BigInteger` and write a print method that spews out a few chars at a time until the entire `BigInteger` is printed, but I rather suspect that the problem lies elsewhere.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Hmm, this code works fine for me, and also works fine here: http://ideone.com/EA0yl.

Comment: I think the problem might be your terminal. Try printing it to a file instead.

Comment: You can debug the runtime.  Use the jdk - it has source

Comment: The number 2^15544 [has 4680 decimal digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^15544). It shouldn't be nowhere near the array length limit. I'd suspect your console to be the source of the problem. Which IDE/console are you using?

Comment: I'm working in Eclipse Indigo on Win 7 x64. And I agree that the ideone result doesn't line up with mine. [Bumping](http://ideone.com/OEk1c) up the value on it, however makes it runtime error out 10 MB and one second before the execution cutoff on ideone.

I agree that a terminal error seems most likely in light of it working elsewhere.

Comment: Huh. On Eclipse Helios, Win XP SP3 32-bit, Java 7, I can reproduce your problem - just with a different exponent. 2^13604 is the first number that fails for me (number length 4096!!). Further inspection shows that the string is okay, it just isn't printed to the console for some reason.

Comment: it works on terminal on MacOSX lion

Comment: It seems that there is a hard limit on a line length without CRLF, in my case it's 4096. However, when I tried setting `Fixed width console` in Console preferences, the number appeared right away.

Comment: It can be reproduced even on Eclipse Juno (Eclipse 4.2), [I found no filed bug about it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=console+line+length) and no word on this in the documentation. Going to file a bug and summarize all this into an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is a bug of the Console view in Eclipse.

On my setup, Eclipse (Helios and Juno) can't show a single line longer than 4095 characters without CRLF. The maximum length can vary depending on your font choice - see below.

Therefore, even the following code will show the problem - there's no need for a `BigInteger`.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    str.append('?');
}
System.out.println(str);
```

That said, the string is actually printed in the console - you can for instance copy it out of it. It is just not shown.

As a workaround, you can set `Fixed width console` setting in Console preferences, the string will immediatelly appear:

[image: view of the pref]

The corresponding bugs on Eclipse's bugzilla are:

- [Display problem in console when a line reaches 4096 characters](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353197)
- [Texteditor can't show a line with more than 4095 chars. Limit at 4096 chars.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372241)
- [Long lines are not displayed by editor](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23406)

According to those, it's a Windows/GTK bug and Eclipse's developers can't do anything about it.

> The bug is related to the length of the text is pixels, use a smaller
>   font and you will be able to get more characters in the text before it
>   breaks.

Comment: Sure enough the result shows with fixed width console enabled. I should have done better problem isolation. Thank you for your time.