# Limited BigInteger in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I get a value for `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(31093)`, but not for `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(31094)` (its empty).

I edited my eclipse.ini like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard_2.0.2.20140224-0000
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform 
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=1024M
```

On other computers I succeeded. Is eclipse still the problem or there is something else?

Comment: Could you please be more clear as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=500

Comment: What do you mean by 'its empty'? Show us the code you are running, what to get and what you expected to get.

Comment: OMG its so weird! On debug, BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(31094) is filled with zeroes (only a variable named mag has a value of 1048576). If I print them with sysout, 31093 writes something and 31094 writes nothing. BUT - I wanted to c&p the value printed (to show you), and a huge number got copied! It *looks* empty without any value, but if you copy it something gets copied! So strange! What is wrong in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it interest anyone - The problem is a bug of the Console view in Eclipse.

[Printing very big BigIntegers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173698/printing-very-big-bigintegers) - same problem. The workaround works.